# Blender 2.8 drivers, trigonometric functions not working?

Tags: drivers

I am trying to make an object rotate based on its position. Basically the Y-angle

***gamma = arcsin(var)***

where ***var*** is the driver variable connected to the x-location of the object.

The only problem is that blender does recognize ***sin()*** but neither ***asin()*** nor ***arcsin()***. According to the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/drivers_panel.html) of 2.79, ***asin()*** should work.

Is this a missing feature or has it changed in 2.8?

EDIT: If this is missing, would a taylor series of arcsin work? I could imagine that that would significantly decrease performance.

Comment: If it's featured in the documentation but not working, either the documentation needs to be updated, or more likely: it's a bug. Either way, I would [file a bug report](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/project/2/type/Bug/).

Answer (score 2):

**Domain Error**

My suspicion is rather than `asin` being unavailable, you are getting a math domain error.

in python console

```
>> "asin" in bpy.app.driver_namespace
True

>>> bpy.app.version
(2, 80, 74)
```

Indicating the `math.asin(angle)` method is known to driver namespace.  *Would seriously consider not filing a bug report re it missing*

To test have typed `#asin(frame)` directly into x location of an object (`frame` , also in driver namespace, is current frame)

[image]

and as expected at frame 1, returns $\pi/2$ (or 90 degrees).

Remember the values passed to $\arcsin(x)$ need to be in domain [-1. 1], hence if i change to frame 2

```
ERROR (bke.fcurve): ../fcurve.c:2084 driver_evaluate_simple_expr: Math Domain Error in Driver: 'asin(frame)'
```